# Does Imposing a Constraint Make a Method More Powerful?

Tags: self-study, panel-data, experiment-design, inference, statistical-power

Suppose we have 100 patients in a randomized trial. Fifty of them are in the treatment group and the rest are in the placebo group. This is a longitudinal study so that we measure the response from each individual at four different periods: baseline, week 1, week 4, and week 6.

Now suppose we have good reason to assume that "the two groups (treatment group and placebo group) have the same mean response at baseline". But one researcher  considered the method with the assumption (Method 1) and another researcher considered the method without the assumption (Method 2). Both researchers got equivalent results.

Now my question is while the assumption of equal mean of baseline in different groups hold, then why do not considering the assumption make the method *LESS POWERFUL* while I am getting equivalent results from both the two methods?

The question arose after reading [p.128 and p.129 of the book "Applied Longitudinal Analysis".](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=0exUN1yFBHEC&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=Alternative%20methods%20of%20adjusting%20for%20baseline%20response&source=bl&ots=BcnTXVvM-E&sig=lSUaahQ12VeFDe7zRb8hYrXMxKU&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Alternative%20methods%20of%20adjusting%20for%20baseline%20response&f=false)

Thank you.

Comment: While considering this, note that the use of the baseline as the first follow-up measurement (which I assume you are doing because that's the only way the equal means assumption is needed) is controversial.  I have detailed notes about that in Chapter 7 of Regression Modeling Strategies for which course notes are available at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms.

Comment: Please edit to include a complete reference (author/title/year at the very least)